# Bit masking in C - How to get first bit of a byte?

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I have:

`int8_t byteFlag;`

and I want to get the first bit of it? I think I probably need to use `&` and `>>` but not sure how exactly. Any help?

Comment: By first bit, do you mean Most Significant or Least Significant ?

Comment: I mean Most Significant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int func(int8_t byteFlag, int whichBit)
{
    if (whichBit > 0 && whichBit <= 8)
        return (byteFlag & (1<<(whichBit-1)));
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Now `func(byteFlag, 1)` will return 1'st bit from LSB. You can pass `8` as `whichBit` to get 8th bit (MSB).

`<<` is a left shift operant. It will shift the value `1` to the appropriate place and then we have to do `&` operation to get value of that particual bit in `byteFlag`.

for `func(75, 4)`

```
75         -> 0100 1011
1          -> 0000 0001
1 << (4-1) -> 0000 1000 //means 3 times shifting left
```

`75 & (1 << (4 - 1))` will give us `1`.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't upvote for now :( Could you please give more explanation about 1 << (whichBit-1) do? for example, if whichBit is 3, what does 1 << 2 do? I understand that << is shift left

Comment: Does the output of this depend on processor endianness, or is it always big endian?

Answer (score 3):

You would use the & operator.

If by "first bit" you mean LSB:

```
int firstBit = byteFlag & 1;
```

If by "first bit" you mean MSB:

```
int firstBit = byteFlag >> (sizeof(byteFlag) * 8 - 1);
```

Comment: Technically it's the last bit you're getting :P

Comment: `int8_t` is guaranteed to be 1 byte in size.

Comment: @Jesus: no, there are different conventions on the numbering of bits.

Comment: @PaulR I should say at least 1 byte in size.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to get the 3-th bit? I don't know how to use shift

Comment: @user1997839 It sounds like you just need to learn a bit about bit shifting: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Answer (score 3):

Just mask the high bit

```
int8_t high_bit = byteFlag & (1 << 7); //either 1 or 0
```

Another trick since this is a signed int

```
if (byteFlag < 0) firstBitSet = true;
```

The last one works because of the representation of numbers in two's complement. The high bit is set if the number is negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
int8_t bit_value = (byteFlag & (1U << bitPosition)) ? 1 : 0 ;
/* now it's up to you to decide which bit is the "first".
   bitPosition = 0 is the minor bit. */
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given below. To get first bit of number, set bit = 1;

```
int bitvalue(int8_t num, int bit)
{
    if (bit > 0 && bit <= 8)
        return ( (num >> (bit-1)) & 1 );
    else
        return 0;
}
```